# Possible database configuration problems

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm a new Zend developper and I have got some conception problem's (especially with doctrine).

I've got a Class which is called MyAuthenticationProcess.
This class is trying to authenticate an User by verifiying his identity on a Database.

As I saw over the internet, I should implement 3 things in order to communicate with my dataBase.

First of all, I have to add those lines in my module.config.php

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__. '_driver' => array(
                    'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                    'cache' => 'array',
                    'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__.'\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__.'_driver'      
                )       
            )   
    )       
),
```

Secondly I have to create a file which will contains my Entity. I created this file in Authentification/Entity/User.php

Here is the code of this file :

```
<?php
namespace Authentification\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;


   /**
 * A User table.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @property string $login
 * @property string $password
 * @property int $id
 */

class User {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $login;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $password;


/**
 * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
 *
 * @param string $property
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __get($property)
{
    return $this->$property;
}

/**
 * Magic setter to save protected properties.
 *
 * @param string $property
 * @param mixed $value
 */
public function __set($property, $value)
{
    $this->$property = $value;
}


}
?>
```

And to finish I added this configuration into this file : config/autoload/local.php

```
    <?php

return array(


    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname' => 'zf2tutorial',
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

The problem that I have now is for accessing to my dataBase.
I guess it's a problem of configuration.

In my class MyAuthenticationProcess I'm trying to get all the entries of my table "User". But I can't.

Here is the code that I used to do so :

```
    $users = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Authentification\Entity\User')->findAll()   ;
    var_dump($users) ;
```

And here is the error that I get :

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template &quot;layout/layout&quot;; resolver could not resolve to a file' in xampp\htdocs\kjsencha\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php:457
Stack trace:
#0 xampp\htdocs\kjsencha\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(201): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer-&gt;render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#1 xampp\htdocs\kjsencha\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(126): Zend\View\View-&gt;render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy-&gt;render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#3 xampp\htdocs\kjsencha\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(460): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) in <b>\xampp\htdocs\kjsencha\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php</b> on line <b>457</b><br />
```

To make sure that is a problem of configuration I tried to know if the connection was established by using this :

```
    $users = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()   ;
    var_dump($users) ;
```

I was surprise to see that users equals to NULL.

Do you have any idea where the problem came from ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with Doctrine. The layout-template is not found. (Aside: please use SPACES in your code and get rid of all the Tabs ;) )

Comment: Thank you Sam =D
Sorry this is my first time in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found where my problem came from =D

It was my table structure in my database. It was not similar to my entity files, so I change it and now it work.

Hope my post will help someone else which has the same problem.